# Switcher bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script

I want an executable script that changes screen configuration from 1 to 2 or from 2 to 1. I would need a boolean or a variable where the state is saved. It's that possible?

Otherwise, how can I check with xrandr if i'm using config 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably ask `xrandr` what your current configuration is, and parse that output to decide.

However, failing that, to actually answer the question, the usual method for this is testing for the existence of a file:

```
if [ -f /tmp/screenstate1 ]; then
    rm /tmp/screenstate1
    echo "switching to state 2"
else
    touch /tmp/screenstate1
    echo "switching to state 1"
fi
```